# Android static method vs object creation

Tags: java, android

Having a problem with my Android application. I currently have a `CatDownloadService` which is suppose to do 2 things in the background:

1. Download the information of the cat (id, name, imageid, etc...)
   from the server as JSON
2. Parse the JSON into an Cat object
3. Insert the Cat object into the database through a
   CatDatabaseAccessObject
4. Download image of cat
5. Save image onto external storage.

I can't seem to decide between the various ways of achieving this. Can someone point me into the right direction? What I understand about each method is in the ().

**Parse JSON**

1. method in CatDownloadService (Since my JSON parsing would only be
   needed in this class)

   ```
   parseCatJSON(jsonString);
   ```
2. method in CatJSONParser.java (Neater, since the logic for JSON
   parsing is in a class by itself)

   ```
   CatJSONParser catJsonParser = new CatJSONParser();
   catJsonParser.parseCatJSON(jsonString);
   ```
3. static method in CatJSONParser.java (Same as 2. Don't need object
   creation)

   ```
   CatJSONParser.parseCatJSON(jsonString);
   ```

**Add into database through DatabaseAccessObject**

1. method in CatDatabaseAccessObject.java (Each context that uses
   the DBHelper is different)

   ```
   CatDatabaseAccessObject catDAO = new CatDatabaseAccessObject(this);
   catDAO.addCat(cat);
   ```
2. static method in CatDatabaseAccessObject.java (Ensure there is
   only 1 connection to DB)

   ```
   CatDatabaseAccessObject.addCat(cat);
   ```

**Save Cat image to external storage**

1. method in CatStorageManager.java

   ```
   CatStorageManager catStorageManager = new CatStorageManager();
   catStorageManager.writeCatImage(catInputStream);
   ```
2. static method in CatStorageManager.java

   ```
   CatStorageManager.writeCatImage(catInputStream);
   ```

I'm really lost.

Comment: Although this probably isn't particularly helpful, I think it probably depends on your overall solution design. I personally have tended to use static methods in a class for managing reading from and writing to databases, but then it has made sense in the solutions I have been working with. It feels conceptually simpler to me. I am sure there are reasons you wouldn't want to do that in other designs.

Answer (score 0):

I categories static Method in two ways -

- Harmful if they are keeping some misleading and unnecessary references.

  ```
  public static InputStream is = null;
  public static void harfulStaticMethod(InputStream is) {
  BatteryManagerC.is = is;
  /* Read Content */
  /* Leave open or is have used at multiple places */
  }
  ```
- Non Harmful only used to access method variables

  ```
  public static void unharmFullStaticMethod(int a, int b) {
  int c = a + b;
  Log.e("Some Is=", String.valueOf(c));
  }
  ```

As your question is broad and lead to many points. so its just reflect one View. Hope it help you